# Gradle + AspectJ log tracing is trying to recompile the project during “instrumentation” and failing

Tags: java, gradle, aspectj, gradle-plugin, aspectj-maven-plugin

**Edit:**

I've pushed dummy source code here https://github.com/swapnil-kotwal-sp/basic-demo

It seems to be compiling as well as doing AspectJ `instrumentation` as well?

But, I'm getting warning during `instrumentation` as

```
[ant:iajc] [warning] build config error: skipping missing, empty or
 corrupt aspectpath entry: 
/Users/swapnil.kotwal/Downloads/basic-demo/my-demo/src/com/my/demo/TracingAspect.java
```

Can someone help me with getting this `TracingAspect.java` issues fixed?

My ant target look like as below.. which I've converted into Gradle build script as shown in next `code block`

```
<target name="weave-aspects" depends="compile, jar-common" unless="weave.suppressed"
          description="weaves the AspectJ's aspects into classes compiled by compile target">
    <taskdef resource="org/aspectj/tools/ant/taskdefs/aspectjTaskdefs.properties">
      <classpath>
        <pathelement location="${abcd.proj.base}/lib/aspectj-1.9.4/aspectjtools-1.9.4.jar" />
      </classpath>
    </taskdef>

    <echo message="Weaving the AspectJ's aspects into class files ..." />

    <iajc inpath="${classes}" destdir="${classes}"
          debug="true" fork="true"
          maxmem="${iajc.memoryLimit}"
          source="${javaVersion}">
    <!-- path of jar containing TracingAspect -->
    <aspectpath>
       <path>
         <fileset dir="${pqr.bundle.image}" includes="pqr-bundle-common*.jar" />
       </path>
    </aspectpath>
    <classpath>
       <pathelement path="${deps}" />
       <pathelement path="${abcd.proj.base}/lib/aspectj-1.9.4/aspectjrt-1.9.4.jar" />
      </classpath>
    </iajc>
  </target>
```

Gradle conversion is as

```
plugins {
        id "io.freefair.aspectj.post-compile-weaving" version "5.1.1"
        //id "aspectj.gradle" version "0.1.6"
        //id "aspectj.AspectjGradlePlugin" version "0.0.3"
    }

configurations {
    ajc
    aspects
    compile {
        extendsFrom aspects
    }
}

ext {
    aspectjVersion = '1.9.2'
}

dependencies {
    implementation gradleApi() // for custom gradle task/pugin development

    compile project('my-project')
    compile project('my-project1')
    compile project('my-project2')
    // ...

    ajc "org.aspectj:aspectjtools:$aspectjVersion"
    compile "org.aspectj:aspectjrt:$aspectjVersion"
    compile "org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:$aspectjVersion"
    aspects project('my-project1')
    // ...
}


compileJava {
    dependsOn configurations.ajc.getTaskDependencyFromProjectDependency(true, "compileJava")

    doLast{
        System.out.println("Java Version: " + JavaVersion.current());
        ant.taskdef( resource:"org/aspectj/tools/ant/taskdefs/aspectjTaskdefs.properties", classpath: configurations.ajc.asPath)

        ant.iajc(
                maxmem: "1024m", fork: "true", Xlint: "ignore",
                destDir: sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs.asPath,
                //my-common.jar consist of my own AspectTracing.class
                aspectPath: "$projectDir/image/pqr-bundle-common*.jar",
                //aspectPath: configurations.aspects.asPath,
                sourceRootCopyFilter: "**/*.java",
                classpath: configurations.compile.asPath,
                source: project.sourceCompatibility,
                target: project.targetCompatibility
        ){
            sourceroots{
                sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs.each{
                    //ignoring root project and adding only sub-modules
                    if(!it.absolutePath.contains("/src/main/java")) {
                        pathelement(location: it.absolutePath)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `TracingAspect.java` look like this. This class is a part of `aspectpath` jar

```
    <aspectpath>
       <path>
         <fileset dir="${pqr.bundle.image}" includes="pqr-bundle-common*.jar" />
       </path>
    </aspectpath>
```

```
/*
 * The pertypewithin causes all classes that don't have the Untraced annotation
 * to be woven. The pointcuts further limit the use of the tracing loggers to
 * avoid infinite recursion, etc...
 */
@Aspect("pertypewithin(!is(InterfaceType) && !is(EnumType) && (!@my.common.logging.Untraced "
        + "(my-somepackaje..* || my-anotherpackage..*)))")
@Untraced
public class TracingAspect {

    private MyLogger myLogger;
    private static final String ENTERING_PREFIX = "Entering {0}";
    private static final String EXITING_PREFIX = "Exiting {0}";
    private static final String ARGUMENTS = ": Arguments =>";
    private static final String ARGUMENTS_NOT_AVAILABLE = ARGUMENTS + " N/A";
    private static final String RETURN = ", Returns =>";
    private static final String RETURN_NOT_AVAILABLE = RETURN + " N/A";
    private static final String THROWING = "Throwing {0}";

    @Pointcut("staticinitialization(*)")
    public void staticInit() {
    }

    /**
     * This is run in a static initializer block for every woven class, and is
     * used to initialize the trace logger for the class.
     */
    @After("staticInit()")
    public void initLogger(JoinPoint.StaticPart jps) {
        myLogger = MyLogger.getLogger(jps.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName());
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Pointcuts
    //
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    @Pointcut("execution(new(..))")
    void tracedConstructors() {
    }

    // The !execution(String toString()) avoids infinite recursion by not
    // tracing toString() methods.
    // Also, don't trace the compile-time inserted 'access$nnn' methods. That
    // might (in very specific cases) lead to recursion but more generally just
    // confusing.
    @Pointcut("execution(* *(..)) && !execution(String toString()) && !execution(* access$*(..)) "
            + "&& !@annotation(my.common.logging.Untraced)")
    void tracedMethods() {
    }

    // Advice starts below.

    @Before("tracedConstructors()")
    public void traceConstructorEntry(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) {
        if (null != myLogger)
            myLogger.trace(() -> entering(thisJoinPoint.getSignature().getName(), thisJoinPoint.getArgs()));
    }

    @AfterReturning("tracedConstructors()")
    public void traceConstructorExit(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) {
        if (null != myLogger)
            myLogger.trace(() -> exiting(thisJoinPoint.getSignature().getName(), thisJoinPoint.getArgs(), null));
    }

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "tracedConstructors()", throwing = "t")
    public void traceConstructorThrow(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint, Throwable t) {
        if (null != myLogger)
            myLogger.trace(() -> MessageFormat.format(THROWING, thisJoinPoint.getSignature().getName()) + " - "
                    + t.toString());
    }

    @Before("tracedMethods()")
    public void traceMethodEntry(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) {
        if (null != myLogger)
            myLogger.trace(() -> entering(thisJoinPoint.getSignature().getName(), thisJoinPoint.getArgs()));
    }

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "tracedMethods()", returning = "r")
    public void traceMethodExit(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint, Object r) {
        // Add sensitive return value to log context
        if (((MethodSignature) thisJoinPoint.getSignature()).getMethod()
                .getAnnotation(SensitiveTraceReturn.class) != null) {
            LogContext.addSensitiveValue(r);
        }
        if (null != myLogger){
            myLogger.trace(() -> exiting(thisJoinPoint.getSignature().getName(), thisJoinPoint.getArgs(), r));
        }
    }

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "tracedMethods()", throwing = "t")
    public void traceMethodThrow(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint, Throwable t) {
        if (null != myLogger)
            myLogger.trace(() -> MessageFormat.format(THROWING, thisJoinPoint.getSignature().getName()) + " - "
                    + t.toString());
    }

    // End of Advice

    /**
     * Creates entering message trace statement
     *
     * @param method
     *            method name of the log entry
     * @param args
     *            {@code Object} array representing the message parameters
     */
    private String entering(String method, Object[] args) {
        StringBuffer msgBuffer = new StringBuffer(ENTERING_PREFIX);
        Object[] temp = { method };

        if (args != null && args.length > 0) {
            int index = 1;
            msgBuffer.append(ARGUMENTS);
            for (Object arg : args) {
                if (index > 1) {
                    msgBuffer.append(",");
                }
                msgBuffer.append(" {").append(index).append("}");
                index++;
            }
            temp = ArrayUtils.addAll(temp, args);
        } else {
            msgBuffer.append(ARGUMENTS_NOT_AVAILABLE);
        }

        return MessageFormat.format(msgBuffer.toString(), temp);
    }

    /**
     * Creates exiting message trace statement
     *
     * @param method
     *            method name of the log entry
     * @param args
     *            {@code Object} array representing the message parameters
     * @param returnValue
     *            return value from the method, if any
     */
    private String exiting(String method, Object[] args, Object returnValue) {
        StringBuffer msgBuffer = new StringBuffer(EXITING_PREFIX);
        Object[] temp = { method };

        int index = 1;
        if (args != null && args.length > 0) {
            msgBuffer.append(ARGUMENTS);
            for (Object arg : args) {
                if (index > 1) {
                    msgBuffer.append(",");
                }
                msgBuffer.append(" {").append(index).append("}");
                index++;
            }
            temp = ArrayUtils.addAll(temp, args);
        } else {
            msgBuffer.append(ARGUMENTS_NOT_AVAILABLE);
        }

        if (null != returnValue) {
            msgBuffer.append(RETURN).append(" {").append(index).append("}");
            temp = ArrayUtils.addAll(temp, new Object[] { returnValue });
        } else {
            msgBuffer.append(RETURN_NOT_AVAILABLE);
        }
        temp = ArrayUtils.addAll(temp, args);

        return MessageFormat.format(msgBuffer.toString(), temp);
    }
}
```

Where the `interface :- my.common.logging.Untraced` is just empty (for now)

```
public @interface Untraced {
}
```

But, it is failing during `instrumentation` for with random compilation error.

(Note: without aspectJ my compilation, jar creation happens properly.)

Usually, AspectJ should do log tracing weaving but it is trying to compile it again and hence failing. Any clue what am I missing here?

The Java code for which it is failing is something like below:

```
private static void runRule(boolean before) {
    String str = (before) ? "before" : "after" ;
}
```

**Error is:**

```
[error] Syntax error, insert "|| Expression" to complete Expression
[ant:iajc] String str = (before) ? "before" : "after" ;
[ant:iajc]
```

Comment: I've added `TracingAspect.java` class.. Other multi-module projects are having business logic and I fear it would be possible for me to post here. I can't provide that details because of it's sensitivity. I'm fine with pure `gradle` implementation but didn't get any proper documentation for those plugins

Comment: I've pushed dummy source code here https://github.com/swapnil-kotwal-sp/basic-demo it is compiling properly and trying to add tracing( `TracingAspect.java` have some issues and I'm working on it)

Comment: Thanks to your GitHub project I can see that when calling the Ant task you are trying to use a path to a `*.java` source file as your aspect path instead of a directory containing `*.class` files or a `*.jar` library. I think it is obvious why that would not work. But I still think you should use a Gradle plugin instead. BTW, I could help you much better with Maven, I don't speak Gradle. But someone else probably can if she clones your project and helps you fix it.

Comment: My implementation is not purely in `Gradle` but it has unblocked me(ablest for now), if you can help me & community to get pure Gradle implementations... please go ahead with your answer too. Thanks. 

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've pushed working example demo code here https://github.com/swapnil-kotwal-sp/basic-demo

I also able to fix my business project issue during `instrumentation`, the problem was with below pice of code.

```
private static void runRule(boolean before) {
    String str = (before) ? "before" : "after" ;
}
```

Basically AspectJ doesn't like those circular brackets around `boolean before`, I changed my code and AspectJ started working fine.

```
private static void runRule(boolean before) {
    String str = before ? "before" : "after" ;
}
```

Comment: What are you talking about? `runRule` does not even exist in your repository. And you had a bunch of other errors in it, including the configuration mistake `aspectPath: "$projectDir/my-demo/src/com/my/demo/TracingAspect.java",` I mentioned before. I pulled your last commits and cannot even import the project into Gradle. Other Gradle project build fine on my machine. So how is this problem fixed? You posted a broken project.

Comment: Please pull the latest code. You shouldn't not face any issues. If you read my last comment, I explicitly mentioned that I'm facing some issues but I'm working on it. I think you just need to pull latest code.

Comment: only problem with demo project is I haven't changed the `TracingAspect.java` file to incorporate my dummy code `log tracing` but currently I can't invest time for it. I'll work on it in some sweet time. My business problem is solved and that's most important for me at this moment

Comment: I did pull the latest code, like I said, even before you told me to. The Gradle daemon is not starting, neither on the command line (Windows cmd or Git Bash) nor in IntelliJ IDEA. I just pulled again, but there are no new commits since I last tried. And still no `runRule` in your repository.

Comment: I gave up on the Gradle thing and just tried to compile the Java method you had problems with in a separate AspectJ project. I could reproduce the problem and believe it to be a parsing bug in the AspectJ compiler. So I created an [issue](https://github.com/eclipse/org.aspectj/issues/20) for it. So this is not about your Ant to Gradle migration but simply about AspectJ compilation. The same would have happened in your old Ant project. That you initially had misconfigured the compiler Ant task with the source file name, was just another problem obscuring this one.

Comment: **Update:** The problem is that your variable name is `before` (thanks to Andy Clement for pointing that out), which is one of the reserved keywords for native AspectJ syntax, e.g. the pointcut `before() : execution(* *(..))`. This makes the parser treat it differently from ordinary variable names. You should avoid AJ keywords in code compiled with the AspectJ compiler. But if you watch the issue I created last time, you can see if the grammar can be updated to accommodate your case even when using something like `(before)`.

Comment: Yeah... I wasn't sure if this was `AspectJ` reserved keyword but just removing those circular brackets solved the compilation Issues. But, Yes... I would avoid this keywords. Thank you :)